# Delete header row of CSV import after first import

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on getting a piece of code, which is working and imports all CSV files from a given directory.

```
Sub ImportAllCsv()
  Dim FName As Variant, R As Long

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CSV data").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "CSV data"

  R = 1
  FName = Dir("C:\VBA\CSVs\*.csv")
  Do While FName <> ""
    ImportCsvFile FName, Sheets("CSV data").Cells(R, 1)
    R = Sheets("CSV data").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
    FName = Dir

  Loop
End Sub

Sub ImportCsvFile(FileName As Variant, Position As Range)
  With Sheets("CSV data").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
      "TEXT;" & "C:\VBA\CSVs\" & FileName, Destination:=Position)
      .FieldNames = True
      .RowNumbers = False
      .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
      .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
      .BackgroundQuery = True
      .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
      .SavePassword = False
      .SaveData = True
      .AdjustColumnWidth = True
      .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
      .TextFilePlatform = xlMacintosh
      .TextFileStartRow = 1
      .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
      .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
      .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
      .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
      .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
      .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
      .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
      .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ","
      .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
      .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With
End Sub
```

This piece of code works, however one thing I cannot seem to get implemented is to get rid of the header row of all CSV files **EXCEPT** the first imported CSV.

**Expected result**

Get the code to exclude the header rows for all the CSV files that are imported after the first file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add one of the properties that the macro recorder does not auto-magically include. The [QueryTable.TextFileStartRow Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/querytable-textfilestartrow-property-excel)  allows you to skip a number of rows at the top of the text file.

This may be best passed in as a parameter.

```
...
R = 1
FName = Dir("C:\VBA\CSVs\*.csv")
Do While FName <> ""
    ImportCsvFile FName, Sheets("CSV data").Cells(R, 1), abs(r<>1)+1
    R = Sheets("CSV data").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
    FName = Dir
Loop

Sub ImportCsvFile(FileName As Variant, Position As Range, startRow as long)
  With Sheets("CSV data").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
      "TEXT;" & "C:\VBA\CSVs\" & FileName, Destination:=Position)
      .TextFileStartRow = startRow   '<~~ new parameter
      .FieldNames = True
      .RowNumbers = False
      .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
      .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
      .BackgroundQuery = True
      .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
      .SavePassword = False
      .SaveData = True
      .AdjustColumnWidth = True
      .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
      .TextFilePlatform = xlMacintosh
      .TextFileStartRow = 1
      .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
      .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
      .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
      .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
      .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
      .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
      .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
      .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ","
      .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
      .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I was not aware of that functionality! Many thanks, it fixed it!